# How can I change rotating mode?

Tags: camera

I have got a problem with rotating. I want to rotate a camera and it is rotating around the world origin, when I want to rotate it 'normally'. [image]
Also when I want to scale an object it is moving from world origin... How can I change it?
I hope the question is understable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **pivot point** is set to the 3D Cursor, to change that you either need to press <kbd>.</kbd> and select "**Median Point**" to set it back to blender's default pivot point. or you can find the same options on the top of your 3D viewport as shown below:
[image]

Comment: It is working! Thank you very much.